# RewriteRule or Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

What is the correct RewriteRule for [Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html) ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [NC]
RewriteRule /signupd/(.*?)  https://app.another-domain.com/?%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you try to achieve? Syntactically the `RewriteCond` is incorrect (the second parameter is missing).

Comment: If someone goes to */signupd/some-encrypted-id* it should redirect to *https://app.another-domain.com/some-encrypted-id*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to rewrite the (complete) URI Path `/signupd/some-encrypted-id` to `https://app.example.com/some-encrypted-id` you just need a single rule in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config`:

```
RewriteRule ^/signupd/(.*) https://app.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

and add the `RewriteValve` to your `<Host>`.

**Remark**: Debugging rewrite rules is usually frustrating, therefore you might want to set:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = FINE
```

in `$CATALINA_BASE/logging.properties` and look for entries *"Rewrote X as Y with rule pattern Z"* in the logs (`localhost.<date>.log`).